# Using the UseState hook and use effect hook

Tags: reactjs, function, components, react-hooks, use-effect

Please how do I rewrite this piece of code combine the componentDidMount and componentDidupdate

I have other codes or rather function I need to bring into to the code and as a class-based component, this isn't working.

But a function based component, I will be able to bring in more function into the code.

Thanks.

```js
var ps;

class Dashboard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      backgroundColor: "black",
      activeColor: "info"
    };
    this.mainPanel = React.createRef();
  }
 

  componentDidMount() {
    if (navigator.platform.indexOf("Win") > -1) {
      ps = new PerfectScrollbar(this.mainPanel.current);
      document.body.classList.toggle("perfect-scrollbar-on");
    }
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (navigator.platform.indexOf("Win") > -1) {
      ps.destroy();
      document.body.classList.toggle("perfect-scrollbar-on");
    }
  }
  componentDidUpdate(e) {
    if (e.history.action === "PUSH") {
      this.mainPanel.current.scrollTop = 0;
      document.scrollingElement.scrollTop = 0;
    }
  }
  handleActiveClick = color => {
    this.setState({ activeColor: color });
  };
  handleBgClick = color => {
    this.setState({ backgroundColor: color });
  };
```

What I did which did not work for updating.

```html
var ps;
const Dashboard = (props) => {
  const[backgroundColor, setBackgroundColor] = useState("black");
  const[activeColor, setActiveColor] = useState("info");
  const [handleActiveClick, setHandleActiveClick] =useState({activeColor: 'color'});
  const [handleBgClick, setHandleBgClick] =useState({backgroundColor: 'color'});
  const mainPanel = useRef(null);


  useEffect(()=>{

    if (navigator.platform.indexOf("Win") > -1) {
      ps = new PerfectScrollbar(mainPanel.current);
      document.body.classList.toggle("perfect-scrollbar-on");
    } 
    return () =>{
      ps.destroy();
      document.body.classList.toggle("perfect-scrollbar-on");
  
    }
  },[]);


  useEffect((e)=>{
    if (e.history.action === "PUSH") {
      mainPanel.current.scrollTop = 0;
      document.scrollingElement.scrollTop = 0;
    }
  },['history']);
```

Comment: For `componentDidMount`, you use `useEffect` with an empty array of dependencies. For `componentWillUnmount`, just return a function with the desired functionality from your `useEffect` with an empty dependency array (the mounting one). For `componentDidUpdate` you use `useEffect` and then add the 'history' as a dependency. And state is just `useState` and refs are just `useRef`. That's pretty much everything you need to recreate this, Googling them will show you explanations and examples of all those.

Comment: Please update question with your attempt at functional component conversion and if you are stuck on something.

Comment: @Jayce444 Thanks for the pointer. I was able to destructure the code with a little effort. Please see the update. obviously the history part I didnt get ... and the update didnt happen.

Comment: @DrewReese Thanks for the heads up. Please see what I came up with and the errors above.

Comment: `useEffect` callback doesn't take arguments, and using a string constant in the dependency array means the effect will only be triggered once. Based upon usage in the original class-based component it looks like it is the previous props. Are you simply trying to scroll back to the top of the page when the route changes? Can you explain what the desired functionality should be if my reasoning is incorrect?

Comment: @DrewReese, Thanks you are quite right, the page has a sidebar component. and when one of the links on the sidebar is clicked, the page should scroll back to the top. I didnt write the original code. I am trying to reconstruct it, I am still learning here... I think the first effect toggles the page when the page is loaded and also ends the toggle. While the second to push the new page and scroll the page back to the top.

Comment: @DrewReese I will appreciate if you could reconstruct the code correctly with a bit of explantion of the concept. That will help.. Thanks.

Comment: @AdeolaOni the dependencies for `useEffect` shouldn't be strings, they should literally point to the actual value that's a dependency, e.g. `useEffect(() => {}, [props.history])`

Comment: @AdeolaOni I think there's a couple ways of going about this. (1) is continue the way you've gone and scroll to top when the route changes, can you post more/all of `Dashboard` so it's more clear how it receives the route-props, or (2) Move the scroll to top logic to the component that triggers it, the sidebar, and share *that* component's code. Lets try the first way.

Comment: @DrewReese the full code for the dashboard is here and the Sidebar. The sidebar is imported into the admin.jsx which is the layout for other pages. https://codepen.io/oneil213/project/editor/XJJEzE

Answer (score 1):

I tried this way

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (navigator.platform.indexOf("Win") > -1) {
        ps = new PerfectScrollbar(mainPanel.current);
        document.body.classList.toggle("perfect-scrollbar-on");
    }

    return () => {
        ps.destroy();
        document.body.classList.toggle("perfect-scrollbar-on");
    };
}, [actionPush(props)]);

function actionPush(props) {
    if (props.history.action === "PUSH") {
        console.log(mainPanel.current);
        mainPanel.current.scrollTop = 0;
        document.scrollingElement.scrollTop = 0;
    }
}
```